# Maximum number of points in a skill per level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, skills

I remember when creating my level 1 rogue many moons ago - for my first Pathfinder game ever - that our GM told us there was a max. number of skill points we could put into each skill.

I don't remember the reason for this, what the limit was or whether any of our group had seen this in the rules. I've not been able to find anything so far. Is anyone able to fill me in?

Comment: Do you mean "how many skill ranks can we have in a skill total" or "how many can we add to a skill when we advance a level?"

Comment: I think I phrased the question poorly - I wondered if there was a limit on the total. All of your answers have been useful, thank you so much to everyone who answered / commented.

Comment: Ah ok, then it's a duplicate.  Will merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can never have more ranks in a skill than your total number of Hit Dice.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/usingSkills.html)

This means that, at level 1, you can only put one rank in each skill.
If, at later levels, you want to add a bunch of skill points in the same skill at once, you can, unless that would break the aforementioned rule.

The reason for this is to avoid having people put all their skill points in a single skill, automatically passing every DC out there way earlier than it would otherwise be possible.
If you want to catch up with a skill you left behind, however, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to: in-game, skill points represent the time your training gives you to get better at skills. Getting a little better at many skills or incredibly better at a single one just depends on how you spend your time.

Answer (score 11):

So just to be clear - there is a TOTAL number of points you can have in a skill (usually equal to your character level, see [What determines max skill rank?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41464/what-determines-max-skill-rank)) - but there is not a cap on how many points you can put in per level as you advance, which may be what you're asking.  If you're a rogue who has ignored Appraise until you turn level 8, for example, you can pour 8 skill points into it at that point.